# ProGuard and SharedPreferences

Tags: android, proguard

Im having problems with the release builds of an Android app. Every time the app is closed and reopened, the persistent cookie store (loopj async-http-client) based on SharedPreferences is empty. This behavior can't be replicated on debug build without minifyEnabled. I have tried to disable all shrinking and optimizations done by proguard (http://pastebin.com/PC2r8mGM) but the problem persists.

Comment: `"disable all shrinking and optimizations done by proguard"`. What is the point of using proguard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable proguard for the library:

```
-keep class com.loopj.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.loopj.android.** { *; }
```

or you can only keep the class you faced the problem. (PersistentCookieStore)

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this problem as well. I fixed it by adding

```
-dontobfuscate
```

To my proguard rules.

Comment: So you are only using Proguard for the shrinking?

Comment: I orginally used dontobfuscate to see if it solved my problem. Now I pulled all of the code that used SharedPreferences into a separate class and excluded it using -keep class com.example.keystore . Similar to Coldfish's answer.